# Python function transfering the pandas Dataframe attributes doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, function

It'a simple example.

```
d=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],
                'b':[6,6,7,8]})
```

I write a function f(x).I want to print d.x. The function is:

```
def f(x):
  print(d.x)
```

Run `f(a)`. I expect it to print `d.a`

But it returns `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`.
How do I solve it?

Comment: how are yo running `f(a)`? Using `.apply()` or explicitly giving `f(a)` some element of d??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't approach it that way, you would need a function that get's column by `[` `]`, and enter a string as well:

```
def f(x):
    print(d[x])
```

And to call it:

```
f('a')
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to write `x.a` if you try to pass dataframe in function which is locally x

```
def f(x):
  print(x.a)
```

but if you pass column name then and dataframe is global variable then you could use below

```
 def f(x):
   print(d[x])
```

Comment: Well, he wants it into the function without knowing variable

Comment: @U9-Forward he is transferring dataframe not column name

Comment: Ugh, now it's really like my answer

Comment: @U9-Forward but there is a comment where i mentioned about the answer

Comment: What do you mean explanation? i got that now